# Angular4 <mat-progress-spinner> how to show and hide when a page load completes

Tags: angular

I am implementing a loading spinner to my application. From this site 
https://material.angular.io/components/progress-spinner/overview
I could not able to get more info to show and hide.  I tried it out, but the spinner is always showing. Please help.

Comment: When you make a backend call, show the spinner before you make a call and hide the spinner inside success callback or `.then()` function. Please add your code to get the answer

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The spinner component just displays the spinner. You have to add show/hide logic by yourself e.g creating a boolean in your component class and setting it to *ngIf directive:

```
<mat-spinner *ngIf="resourcesLoaded === false"></mat-spinner>
```

Comment: `resourcesLoaded === false` sure? Why not simply to `!resourcesLoaded`

Comment: Sure, basically same thing, but "!" notation also accounts cases like `null`, `undefined`, `0` and empty string (in JS that is), so I usually prefer explicit values.

Comment: It doesn't matter i think in this case